# Angular UI/bootstrap typeahead showing 'Error: No controller: ngModel' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my application I am calling an http service to get data and I am using angular-ui bootstrap's typeahead directive (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js). I have a partial that has a form that mentions the controller and it includes a partial inside ng-repeat. This second partial has the typeahead.

Main form partial:

```
<form
    id="myform" 
    name="myform"
    onsubmit="javascript: return false"
    enctype="application/json"
    ng-controller="EducationCollegeCtrl">
    // doing other stuff
    ...

    <div ng-if="model.hasData">
        <div ng-repeat="college in model.academicRecords" ng-form="collegeForm">
            <div ng-include="'resources/appc/modules/main/education/components/collegetype.all.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    // other stuff going on here
```

collegetype.all.html:

```
....
        <label for="institution">Institution name:</label>
        <div>
              <input type="text" ng-model="college.organizationName"  typeahead="item.name for item in matchingInstitutions($viewValue)>
        </div>
        ....
```

EducationCollegeCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('theApp',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('EducationCollegeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   ...
    $scope.matchingInstitutions = function(partialName) {
        return $http.get('lookup/institutions?name=' + partialName ).then(function(response){
            return response.data.institutions;
        }); 
    };

   ...
```

The service gets called and the drop-down shows up correctly with the name of institutions. But in the browser console, I see the below error for every entry in the drop-down

console.log:

```
Error: No controller: ngModel
at Error (<anonymous>)
at getControllers (/resources/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.js:4899:39)
at nodeLinkFn (/resources/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.js:5040:55)
at compositeLinkFn (/resources/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.js:4626:37)
at nodeLinkFn (/resources/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.js:5033:40)
at compositeLinkFn (/resources/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.js:4626:37)
at publicLinkFn (/resources/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.js:4531:46)
at ngRepeatAction (/resources/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.js:15638:33)
at Object.$watchCollectionAction (/resources/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.js:8867:29)
at Object.applyFunction [as fn] (<anonymous>:778:50) <typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope"> angular.js:6422
```

My understanding of the error is that a 'required' attribute in the directive is missing and that is what angular is complaining about, but as you can see in the partial, I do have the ng-model attribute defined and also the controller is specified in the main form partial. What am i missing here ?

EDIT: removed irrelevant parts of url.

Comment: Could you make a plunker so we can examine everything more easily?

Comment: I am also having this problem... totally inexplicable.

Comment: Try changing the name from `model` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-include` creates child `$scope`, that prototypically inherits it's parent `$scope`. That means that your `ng-model="college.organizationName"` won't reference `college` variable in parent but will shadow it. And your new `college` variable won't have `organizationName` property. The most simple way probably will be just not to use `ng-include`, since you have `ng-repeat` and already avoided "don't repeat yourself" rule.